# How to generate exponentially increasing range in Python

Tags: python

I want to test the performance of some code using an exponentially increasing value.  So that as an extra digit is added to the numbers_size the increment is multiplied by 10.  This is how I'm doing it so far but it looks a bit hacky.  Suggestions for improvements without introducing non-standard libraries?

```
numbers_size = 100
increment = 100
numbers_range = 1000000000
while numbers_size < numbers_range:
    t = time.time()
    test( numbers_size )
    taken_t = time.time() - t
    print numbers_size, test, taken_t

    increment = 10 ** (len(str(numbers_size))-1)
    numbers_size += increment
```

Comment: You've got answers, but can I please ask why?

Comment: To see the difference of searching lists and dictionaries for a talk I'm giving on Python performance tips.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To produce the same numbers as your code:

```
numbers_sizes = (i*10**exp for exp in range(2, 9) for i in range(1, 10))
for n in numbers_sizes:
    test(n)
```

Answer (score 24):

If you consider numpy as one of the standards ;), you may use [numpy.logspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) since that is what it is supposed to do.... (note: 100=10^2, 1000000000=10^9)

```
for n in numpy.logspace(2,9,num=9-2, endpoint=False):
    test(n)
```

example 2 (note: 100=10^2, 1000000000=10^9,  want to go at a step 10x, it is 9-2+1 points...):

```
In[14]: np.logspace(2,9,num=9-2+1,base=10,dtype='int')
Out[14]: 
array([       100,       1000,      10000,     100000,    1000000,
         10000000,  100000000, 1000000000])
```

example 3:

```
In[10]: np.logspace(2,9,dtype='int')
Out[10]: 
array([       100,        138,        193,        268,        372,
              517,        719,       1000,       1389,       1930,
             2682,       3727,       5179,       7196,      10000,
            13894,      19306,      26826,      37275,      51794,
            71968,     100000,     138949,     193069,     268269,
           372759,     517947,     719685,    1000000,    1389495,
          1930697,    2682695,    3727593,    5179474,    7196856,
         10000000,   13894954,   19306977,   26826957,   37275937,
         51794746,   71968567,  100000000,  138949549,  193069772,
        268269579,  372759372,  517947467,  719685673, 1000000000])
```

on your case, we use `endpoint=False` since you want not to include the endpoint... (e.g. `np.logspace(2,9,num=9-2, endpoint=False)` )

Comment: If it's fractional, this won't work. Use, e.g.:

`np.geomspace(1e-8, 10, 10, dtype=float)`

Answer (score 20):

Why not

```
for exponent in range(2, 10):
    test(10 ** exponent)
```

if I'm reading your intent right.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest thing to do is to use a linear sequence of exponents:

```
for e in range(1, 90):
    i = int(10**(e/10.0))
    test(i)
```

You can abstract the sequence into its own generator:

```
def exponent_range(max, nsteps):
    max_e = math.log10(max)
    for e in xrange(1, nsteps+1):
        yield int(10**(e*max_e/nsteps))

for i in exponent_range(10**9, nsteps=100):
    test(i)
```

Answer (score 5):

I like Ned Batcheldor's answer, but I would make it a bit more general:

```
def exp_range(start, end, mul):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start *= mul
```

then your code becomes

```
for sz in exp_range(100, 1000000000, 10):
    t = time.time()
    test(sz)
    print sz, test(sz), time.time()-t
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator expression:

```
max_exponent = 100
for i in (10**n for n in xrange(1, max_exponent)):
    test(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

OP wrote "Suggestions for improvements without introducing non-standard libraries?"

Just for completeness, here's a recipe for generating exponential ranges - each element is a fixed factor bigger than the previous:

```
from math import exp
from math import log

def frange(start, stop, numelements):
    """range function for floats"""
    incr = (stop - start) / numelements
    return (start + x * incr for x in range(numelements))

def exprange(start, stop, numelements):
    """exponential range - each element is a fixed factor bigger than the previous"""
    return (exp(x) for x in frange(log(start), log(stop), numelements))
```

Test:

```
print(", ".join("%.3f" % x for x in exprange(3,81,6)))
```

Output:

```
3.000, 5.196, 9.000, 15.588, 27.000, 46.765
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use any libraries or extra function definitions:

```py
for n in [10**m for m in range(d)]:
    print(n)
```

This list comprehension will do what you want.

`d` is a number of digits. Convert to string and calculate the length if needed.

```
d = len(str(numbers_range))
```

Answer (score -2):

**example of 'NOT reading the question properly' and 'NOT how to do it**'

```
for i in xrange(100, 1000000000, 100):
    # timer
    test(i)
    # whatever
```

Is about as simple as it gets... adjust `xrange` accordingly

Comment: this was downvoted (though not by me) presumably because your range is linear, not exponential.

Comment: @msw Fair point and well made - thank you, I'll stick by my mistake (the **read the question properly** and **not how to do it**) though so it stays in the community for reference purposes.

Comment: I serially upvoted some of your older answers that I thought merited it for two reasons: mostly I hate "drive-by" downvoters who don't bother explaining and I appreciate newcomers who contribute. As to why the OP is doing it the really hard way, I share your puzzlement but don't expect we'll hear back on that one.

Comment: @msw Much appreciated - although unnecessary of course :) I only discovered SO because I wanted to ask a question on pandas, and there was no mailing list/contact I could find apart from here. Then, kinda got hooked, and it's always a pleasure to share what I know, and great to learn things I didn't know :) And if I get it wrong, fine, I get it wrong -- I'll take it on the chin - I don't take it personally anyway... but thanks :)