# Generate an exponentially-spaced list of numbers

Tags: c++, generator, exponential

I want to generate an exponentially-spaced list of numbers in C++, where the number of points and the bounds are known (just like Matlab's linspace or logspace, or Python's numpy.logspace). I have found several implementations for log-spaced numbers (see below), but couldn't think of a way to invert these to exponentially-spaced numbers, besides, bounds can be negative.

Here's is what I have found so far :

[Is there something like numpy.logspace in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429294/is-there-something-like-numpy-logspace-in-c)

[EXPLIST: Stata module to generate an exponentially-spaced list of numbers](http://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s426701.htm) (No idea what this language is actually)

[Generating a logarithmically spaced numbers](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/188926/Generating-a-logarithmically-spaced-numbers)

**EDIT :**

I should have given the problem a little more thinking before rushing to stackoverflow, here's what I actually did (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443737/how-to-generate-exponentially-increasing-range-in-python)) :

Given two bounds `first` and `last`, I wanted to generate a `n`-size array that starts with `first` and ends with `last` where each array's element is the exponential of some `x`.

This mathematical problem is a simple series `U(i)` that starts with `U(0) = first` and ends with `U(n) = last` with `U(i) = first * q^i` (for i in {0, 1, ..., n}) and `q = pow(last / first, 1 / (n - 1))`.

Here's a raw code :

```
#include <Eigen\Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

VectorXd expList(double first, double last, DenseIndex n)
{
    VectorXd vector(n); // native C++ array or vector can be used of course
    double m = (double) 1 / (n - 1);
    double quotient = pow(last / first, m);

    vector(0) = first;

    for (DenseIndex i = 1; i < n; i++) // DenseIndex is just a typedef ptrdiff_t from the Eigen library
        vector(i) = vector(i - 1) * quotient;

    return vector;
}
```

This works for any same sign doubles `first` and `last` where `first < last` of course, but It can work for a negative `first` and positive `last` too with a little tweaking.

**Example :**

for first = 50 and last = 300 000 and a 100 elements array

[image: Example]

Comment: FYI: the language *is* [Stata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stata)

Comment: What the hack are you plotting against ? you have 1 1-d vector.

Comment: @FélixCantournet Excel and Matlab plot against elements index if you don't have the x data.

Comment: @Naucle From the actual question you linked : you fundtion is equivalent to pyLogspace(log10(10), log10(100), 9). What you have is a logspace. There is no such thing as an exponential-space.

Comment: @FélixCantournet I never mentioned an exponential-space, I know basic maths. Here, values are spaced exponentially, meaning that the distance between two consecutive values grows exponentially and the natural logarithm of the array is a linear function (log(first*q^i) ~ a + i * b). By the way, english is not my native language, I could be misusing terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you mean is a list of doubles (d1,...,dn) such that e^d(i+1)-e^di is constant?
In that case the following function should do what you want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<double> explist(double first, double last, double size)
{
    if(first>last) std::swap(first,last);
    double expfirst = exp(first);
    double explast = exp(last);
    double step = (explast-expfirst)/(size-1);
    std::vector<double> out;
    for(double x=expfirst; x<=explast; x+=step)
    {
        double a = log(x);
        out.push_back(a);
    }
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> test = explist(0,1,6);
    for(double d : test)
    {
        std::cout<<d<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    for(double d : test)
    {
        std::cout<<exp(d)<<" ";

    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0.295395 0.523137 0.708513 0.86484 1
1 1.34366 1.68731 2.03097 2.37463 2.71828
```

At the moment this function only produces ascending lists (it just assumes that the smaller value is the left bound). There are several ways to make it work for descending lists as well (always assuming the leftmost argument to be the left bound). I just wanted to make the function as simple as possible and I think if you understand the function it will be easy for you to add that functionality.

Comment: Even though this is not was I was looking for, I thank you for the effort.